# Executing powershell.exe from powershell script (run in ISE but not in script)

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I'm new to these awesome Power shell world.  I have a problem with script and really apreciate your help.

I have a script "cmd4.ps1" that needs to run another script "Transfer.ps1" that needs to receive 3 strings params and it needs to be run as other process thead different to "cmd4.ps1".

cmd4.ps1:

```
$Script="-File """+$LocalDir+"\Remote\Transfer.ps1"" http://"+$ServerIP+"/Upload/"+$FileName+" "+$ServerIP+" "+$LocalIP

Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $Script
```

After ejecution, the `$Script` cointain a value similar to

```
-File "c:\temp re\Remote\Transfer.ps1" http://10.1.1.1/Upload/file.txt 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.10
```

containing the syntax to use `-File` parameter to run a script of Powershell.exe, and three parameters that Transfer.ps1 needs (`"http://10.1.1.1/Upload/file.txt", 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.10`).

When I write these instructions in PowerShell ISE I can see every values are right and PowerShell.exe is executed with right values, everything work fine!, but if I put these instructions inside "cmd4.ps1" script it doesn't work, I mean something is not right with parameters because I can see it start powershell but it never ends.

Answer (score 1):

`-ArgumentList` is expecting an array of string arguments instead of a single string.  Try this instead:

```
$ScriptArgs = @(
    '-File'
    "$LocalDir\Remote\Transfer.ps1"
    "http://$ServerIP/Upload/$FileName $ServerIP $LocalIP"
)

Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $ScriptArgs
```

Note that you can simplify the string construction of the args as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put this in cmd4.ps1?

```
& "c:\temp re\Remote\Transfer.ps1" "http://10.1.1.1/Upload/file.txt" "10.1.1.1" "10.1.1.10"
```